# Python: separate list of values into x number of sections, and give each value in x a variable

Tags: python, iteration

I have a list of numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, a list of colours `['red', 'green', 'orange', 'blue']` and a variable `chunks`. Depending on the value of chunks, I will return each number associated with a colour.

For example: `chunks = 2` will return the color for two values

```
1 - red
2 - red
3 - green
4 - green
5 - orange
6 - orange
7 - blue
8 - blue
```

whereas `chunks = 4` will return the color for four values

```
1 - red
2 - red
3 - red
4 - red
5 - green
6 - green
7 - green
8 - green
```

How do I iterate through this list to spit out what i need?

Comment: Does `chuncks` specify the number of `colors` ?

Comment: Yup, that's right. If chunks is '2', i'm splitting the list of numbers into two sections, with 2 colours; if chunks is 4, it's splitting the list into 4 sections with 4 colours.

Comment: What if `chunks` is not a divisor of number list length?
What if `chunks` is greater than colour list length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some index trickery:

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> colors = ['red', 'green', 'orange', 'blue']
>>> chunks = 4
>>> for i,num in enumerate(nums):
    print("%s:%s"%(num,colors[i*chunks//len(nums)%len(colors)]))
1:red
2:red
3:green
4:green
5:orange
6:orange
7:blue
8:blue
```

the major part of this is `colors[i*chunks//len(nums)%len(colors)]` which can be broken down like this:

```
colors[i*chunks//len(nums)%len(colors)]
       ^                              index of num in nums
        ^      ^                      multiply by chunks then later dividing by len is the
                                      same as dividing by len/chunks
               ^                      explicit integer divide is important for indexing
                          ^           ensures that there is no index error if 
                                      chunks>len(colors) (check example)
```

high value of `chunks` example:

```
>>> chunks = 7
>>> for i,num in enumerate(nums):
    print("%s:%s"%(num,colors[i*chunks//len(nums)%len(colors)]))


1:red
2:red
3:green
4:orange
5:blue
6:red
7:green
8:orange
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
colors = ['red', 'green', 'orange', 'blue']
chunkedColors = sorted(colors*(len(numbers)//chunks),key=colors.index)[:len(numbers)]
```

Comment: Editted for `chunks` not divisor of `len(numbers)`